# Parsing complicated polynomial expressions in python

Tags: python, parsing, sympy, polynomials

I have complicated polynomial expressions in string format. For example, `-1/4 + 1/(2*Sqrt[5]) + u^2`, `u^2 + Root[1 + 84*#1 + 560*#1^2 + 448*#1^3 & , 2, 0]`. Is there a way to parse this using `sympy` or any other library in Python?

Here `Root[..., n, 0]` is a mathematical expression, where `Root[-1 - 2*#1 + 39*#1^2 - 7*#1^3 - 261*#1^4 + 63*#1^5 + 441*#1^6 & , 1, 0]` should mean the first root of the polynomial `-1-2*x+39”x^2-7*x^3-… +4413x^6` denote the root of the equation.

**EDIT**

I have the following code which converts the mathematical expression to sympy module. I am struggling to extract various information about the polynomial itself.

```
from sympy.parsing import mathematical
from sympy import Function, Max, Min, sympify

# Define the Mathematica expressions as strings
expr1_str = "-1/4 + 1/(2*Sqrt[5]) + u^2"
expr2_str = "u^2 + Root[1 + 84*#1 + 560*#1^2 + 448*#1^3 &, 2, 0]"

x =  mathematica.parse_mathematica(expr2_str)
```

It returns `sympy.core.add.Add`. It is not clear to me how to convert this into a polynomial expression. I want to know various things about these polynomials, like, degree, coefficients of each term, whether there is a sqrt involved or not, etc.

Comment: Looks like you're parsing a Wolfram Language expression. Basic expressions are easy enough to parse with something like [Lark](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark). However, it looks like parsing the `&` operator [isn't so straightforward](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/159049/how-to-write-a-grammar-with-a-low-precedence-unary-postfix-operator).

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! I edited the question with something that is partially working. I am still unable to get it to do what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sympy's `parse_mathematica`:

```py
from sympy.parsing.mathematica import parse_mathematica
help(parse_mathematica)
```

```py
expr = parse_mathematica("-1/4 + 1/(2*Sqrt[5]) + u^2")
print(expr)
# out: u**2 - 1/4 + sqrt(5)/10
```

```py
expr = parse_mathematica("u^2 + Root[1 + 84*#1 + 560*#1^2 + 448*#1^3 & , 2, 0]")
print(expr)
# out: u**2 + Root(Lambda(_dummy0, 448*_dummy0**3 + 560*_dummy0**2 + 84*_dummy0 + 1), 2, 0)
```

Note the `Root` in the last output: I've never seen that object before, so I don't know what it does/how it works...

EDIT to satisfy the edit in the question:

> I want to know various things about these polynomials, like, degree, coefficients of each term, whether there is a sqrt involved or not, etc.

```py
p = Poly(expr)
```

to return the degree:

```py
p.degree()
```

to get all coefficients:

```py
p.all_coeffs()
```

This is one way to verify if `sqrt` is into the polynomial. Note that `sqrt` is converted to a power operation with exponent 1/2:

```py
len(expr.find(lambda t: t.is_Pow and t.exp is S.Half)) > 0 # or p.find(...)
```

For the `etc.` part, look into documentation...

Comment: Is there a way to convert this ``expr`` into polynomial object. I want to query the object for it's degree, various coefficients, forms of the coefficients, etc.

Comment: That's strange. I am getting this error - ``PolynomialError: non-commutative expressions are not supported`` if I do ``Poly(expr)``.

Comment: I think `Root(lambda x: f(x), i, j)` should be `RootOf(f(x), i)`.

Comment: @smichr I did quick test with `isinstance`. It tested false for `RootOf`, `CRootOf`. Honestly, I have no idea where that `Root` comes out... :|